# can not save data for handsontable in json with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to save and retrieve data in handson table from .json file for save data I have

```
$('button[name=save]').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "json/load.json",
    data: {
      "data": handsontable.getData()
    }, //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) {
      if (res.result === 'ok') {
        alert('Data saved');
      }
      else {
        alert('Save error');
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
      alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    }
  });
});
```

But this does not save data getting `error status:6`, when try to print error. I don't have idea to use json and jquery. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Are you trying to write to a JSON file with a `POST` call using only JS?

Comment: yes ,My simple requirement is to load and save data from a json file.

Comment: @user1806374 You _do_ have some serverside hooked up on the JSON (maybe with a rewrite rule) so the changes will happen there, right? You can't simply POST to a JSON and have it change.. (well https://www.firebase.com/ let you do that, but that's a whole service)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's why I asked. It seems like they want to do the write solely with front-end JS, which is not possible.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I realise that. I use node quite often. I meant in the context of this question, with the code provided. I should have stated that I meant only front-end. Edited previous comment to clarify.

Comment: Is is ok if try to use a web method that accept json as argument ?then How will I pass json argument in the above ajax method..?